# Framing an image with text on top

Tags: android

I have a persistent problem I can't seem to overcome. 
First, what I want to achieve: to select an image from the gallery or take one with the camera, import said image into my app, frame the image with a drawable I have designed with an area marked for the content, display the image on an ImageView, write some text I get from the database on the image+frame, then save image to a specific folder on the SD card.

What I have been able to do so far: I have created a .png image which I use as the frame for the selected image, then I used this drawable as the background of the image view. Upon selection of the image from gallery or taking with the camera, and setting the imageview's 'SRC' to the image does exactly what I want (the image is visibly within the frame).

My questions are:
1. How can I write text (from database) on the frame since it is already a resource I just use as the background of the imageview?
2. how can I retrieve both frame and picture as a single bitmap from the image view? 
3. Am I doing it wrong and is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. put the imageview in a framelayout
2. add a textview on top
3. set textview's text from db
4. draw the framelayout on a bitmap

Comment: Say, the image is actually lodged in a view flipper. Is there any chance the framelayout you are suggesting can wrap the imageview in the viewflipper?

Comment: viewflipper is a framelayout itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I never even knew this was possible